# CodeIgniter 4 problem installing with composer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problems trying to install CodeIgniter 4 via Composer, on a local server (xampp)

The code that throws me is the following:

```
    PS C:\Users\PuercoRico> cd D:\xampp\htdocs
PS D:\xampp\htdocs> composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter ci4 -s rc
Installing codeigniter4/appstarter (4.0.0-rc.4)
  - Installing codeigniter4/appstarter (4.0.0-rc.4): Loading from cache
Created project in ci4
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.2.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework v4.0.0-rc.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - codeigniter4/framework 4.0.0-rc.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for codeigniter4/framework ^4@rc -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0-rc.4, v4.0.0-rc.1, v4.0.0-rc.2, v4.0.0-rc.2.1, v4.0.0-rc.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - D:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

The version of php that I am using is 7.4.1

Any idea what the error may be or how I can fix it.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: `requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system` - which kind of questions are still open? Have you even tried anything to fix this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your PHP is missing **intl** extension. It is useful for formatting currency, number and date/time as well as UCA-conformant collations, for message formatting and normalizing text..etc.

Check out Codeignitor 4 [Documentation][1]:

Follow the steps to install it in XAMPP -

1. Open [xampp_folder_path]/php/php.ini to edit.
2. Search for **;extension=intl** and remove the **;**.
3. Save the php.ini file and restart Apache.

Comment: Guys also this answer here below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67433543/13903942  as it helped me

Answer (score 9):

Quick Fix

1. Open XAMPP Control Panel.
2. Apache -> Select Config & Choose PHP(php.ini)
3. Search for **;extension=intl** and remove the **;**.
4. Save Changes

Restart Apache

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu/Linux and nginx write the following command in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

Comment: Works with Apache as well. Just had to restart Apache.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `intl extension` for PHP So,

- On `ubuntu 20.04` and `PHP 7.4` with `Apache webserver` try:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

- On `ubuntu 20.04` and `PHP 8.0` with `Apache webserver` try:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-intl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

- On `ubuntu 20.04` and `PHP 7.4` with `Nginx webserver` try:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

- On `ubuntu 20.04` and `PHP 8.0` with `Nginx webserver` try:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-intl
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Unable to locate package php7.4-intl

Answer (score 3):

1. Oper Your **XAMPP Control Panel**
2. Click on the **Config** button related to the **Apache** service
3. then Click on **PHP (php.ini)**
4. Open the php.ini file and Find (CTRL+F) **extension=intl**
5. by default that line displays as ***`;extension=intl`***
6. remove the **;** from the line and save the file
7. Restart the Apache server

Answer (score 0):

For fedora distributions used

```
sudo dnf install php-intl
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33313258)