# Failed while installing a package using composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, package, composer-php

iam tryin to use a cart package by using this command

`composer require jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module`

and it's failed. this is what it said

```
Using version dev-master for jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module dev-master -> satisfiable by jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module[dev-master].
    - jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module dev-master requires codeigniter4/framework ^4.0.3 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[v4.0.3, ..., v4.1.1] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but codeigniter4/framework[1.0.0+no-version-set] from root package repo has higher repository priority. The
packages with higher priority do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

is it because my minimum-stability in composer.json is set to "stable"?

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your composer.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you created your project by using `composer create-project codeigniter4/framework`. This effectively created a clean project for you without the `.git` folder, thus removing any metadata on what version of `codeigniter4/framework` package you installed. This is indicative by `1.0.0+no-version-set` part of the error message.

The `jason-napolitano/codeigniter4-cart-module` package requires `^4.0.3` version of `codeigniter4/framework`, but since you have no version metadata in your project, install fails. This can be resolved [by setting the version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version) from which you bootstrapped your project manually in your root `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "codeigniter4/framework",
    "version": "4.0.3",
    ...
}
```

However, this is just a guess, since I have no insight into your main `composer.json`.

Comment: it works. the problem is the version metadata. thx bro.

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP is missing **intl** extension. It is useful for formatting currency, number and date/time as well as UCA-conformant collations, for message formatting and normalizing text..etc.

Check out Codeignitor 4 [Documentation][1]:

Follow the steps to install it in XAMPP -

1. Open [xampp_folder_path]/php/php.ini to edit.
2. Search for **;extension=intl** and remove the **;**.
3. Save the php.ini file and restart Apache.

Comment: the extension that you mentioned above is already activated. and still not work

Comment: Please share more details - where could you find any connection to that extension in the given question?

Comment: I'am really new in this kind of stuff. could you let me know what kind of information that you wish to know?

Comment: please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250533/codeigniter-4-problem-installing-with-composer