# I installed composer 2.0.12. Then when I run "global composer requires CodeIgniter / installer"

Tags: composer-php, codeigniter-4

Problem 1
- codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, ..., v4.1.1] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
- Root composer.json requires codeigniter4/framework ^4 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, ..., v4.1.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Comment: That is Correct and to prevent repeating the answer - please read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250533/codeigniter-4-problem-installing-with-composer