# I have enable PHP Extension intl still showing error?

Tags: codeigniter-4

[PHP Extension intl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B2KM.png)

I am running wamp and php version is 7.3.21 and i have also enabled extension intl but still error.

Error Details:

[CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException]

The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: intl.

at SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php:219

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try searching before posting a new question - I searched for your error msg and found many answers. Have you [enabled the extension in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250533/codeigniter-4-problem-installing-with-composer)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter 4 problem installing with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250533/codeigniter-4-problem-installing-with-composer)